# Push Data to Kafka from Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Can someone provide me sample code to push records to Kafka from Spark Streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Using Spark Streaming, you can consume data from Kafka topic.

If you wanted to publish records to Kafka topic, you can use Kafka Producer [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example]

Or you can use Kafka Connect to publish data to Kafka topic using multiple source connectors.[http://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/]

Please see below link for more information on Spark streaming and Kafka integration.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using Java. You can use this function over a `JavaDStream<String>` as the argument for `.foreachRDD()`. It is not the best way as it creates a `KafkaProducer` for each RDD, you can do this using a "pool" of `KafkaProducers` like the [socket example in Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd).

Here is my code:

```
public static class KafkaPublisher implements VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "loca192.168.0.155lhost:9092");
        props.put("acks", "1");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("batch.size", 16384);
        props.put("linger.ms", 1000);
        props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        rdd.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void call(Iterator<String> partitionOfRecords) throws Exception {
                Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
                while(partitionOfRecords.hasNext()) {
                    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("topic", partitionOfRecords.next()));
                }
                producer.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```